How can I align unordered lists with different div using CSS?
The problem is when the screen size decreases and the three unordered lists are aligned—one for work experience and one for education. The education section doesn't align with the work experience because the text is longer, and I'm using justify-content: space-around. I don't want to use space-between because it creates too much space in the middle, and flex: 1 takes too long to align. How can I solve this?



.info {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 40px;
  gap: 12px;
}

.personal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-indent: 12px;
  gap: 6px;
}

.info ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.info ul li {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.experience {
  color: #282726;
  background-color: #D6CAB0;
}

.personal-experience {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 24px;
}
<section class="experience">
  <h1>Experience & Education</h1>
  <div class="personal-experience">
    <div class="work-experience">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>SOFTWARE ENGINEER</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>MABUHAY INCORPORATED</li>
          <li>(NOVEMBER 2020 - APRIL 2024)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>FRONT END DEVELOPER</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>NARRA INCORPORATED</li>
          <li>(DECEMBER 2019 - NOVEMBER 2020)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="education">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>BACHELOR DEGREE - BSCS</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>YEAR 2015 - 2019</li>
          <li>SCHOOL: UNIVERSIDAD DE SAN JUAN</li>
          <li>ADDRESS: CANLAUN LAGAYAN CITY FINLAND</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




How do you wanna align the items? I did not get what do you actually want.

do you see the image? the div for education is not align horizontally. I want to align it to the work-experience div.

If you want to start the divs at the same point then you have wrap them around parent div and align parent div to center

Do you mean the personal experience div? I already use flex-wrap: wrap and align-items: center same result, It happens when I'm on a screen around 700px.

change the section display to flex and direction to column and align item center and remove space around from the personal experience div. this will solve your problem

"I've already done that, and I'm getting the same result. I think the issue might be that the lengths of the text in the   are not the same.

what I'm saying is just a clue and you'll need to further develop the idea on your own.. anyway those divs are actually aligned correctly... the problem is their text content that as being left aligned, if you won't show their container border, they will look misplaced. A solution in such scenario could be to make the width of those divs the same like a % of the main container. But since you want it responsive you'll need to apply such a rule setting the width using a media query rule that will trigger only when a given max-width is met

can you give an example for the media query and max-width?

@media (max-width: 600) {}. Any css you write between these curly braces will only be applied when the screen size is 600 or less

You can try flex-grow and set a max-width on the work and education containers...


.info {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 40px;
  gap: 12px;
}

.personal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /*
  text-indent: 12px;
  */
  gap: 6px;
}

.info ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.info ul li {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.experience {
  color: #282726;
  background-color: #D6CAB0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.personal-experience {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.work-experience, .education {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 500px;
}
<section class="experience">
  <h1>Experience & Education</h1>
  <div class="personal-experience">
    <div class="work-experience">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>SOFTWARE ENGINEER</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>MABUHAY INCORPORATED</li>
          <li>(NOVEMBER 2020 - APRIL 2024)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>FRONT END DEVELOPER</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>NARRA INCORPORATED</li>
          <li>(DECEMBER 2019 - NOVEMBER 2020)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="education">
      <div class="info">
        <h2>BACHELOR DEGREE - BSCS</h2>
        <ul class="personal">
          <li>YEAR 2015 - 2019</li>
          <li>SCHOOL: UNIVERSIDAD DE SAN JUAN</li>
          <li>ADDRESS: CANLAUN LAGAYAN CITY FINLAND</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



